# Updating the tail in a circular singly linked list

Tags: python, oop, linked-list

I am writing a method to insert a value at a given location in a circular linked list:

```
    def insertCSLL(self,value,location): #Insertion of a node in Singly LL
        if self.head is None:
            return  "The Head refernce is None"
        else:
            newNode = Node(value)
            if location == 0:      # insertion at first position
                newNode.next = self.head
                self.head = newNode
                self.tail.next = newNode
```

In the last line `self.tail.next` points to the `newNode`

Do I also need to write `self.tail = newNode`, so to arrive at this?

```
            newNode = Node(value)
            if location == 0:      # insertion at first position
                newNode.next = self.head
                self.head = newNode
                self.tail.next = newNode
                self.tail = newNode  # <<<
```

Is this last line optional?

Comment: Did you try it both ways? What happens when you try it? What should happen when the code runs? **What do you mean by** "need to"? (In programming, we do not create data structures so that they meet someone else's definition; we create them so that they do something useful, and we make sure they do something useful by **trying to use them and seeing if there is a problem**, i.e. by writing unit tests.)

Comment: Why would you even maintain both `head` and `tail`? In a non-empty circular list `self.tail.next == self.head` is supposed to be always true, so just maintain `self.tail` only.

Comment: As to your question: do you really intend `self.head` to be equal to `self.tail`? Because that is what you are doing in the second code snippet...

Comment: Also, how will you represent an empty list? Why do you not allow insertion when `self.head` is `None`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i have tried both ways now , if i just print(self.tail.next.value) it is pointing to the head but self.tail is still referencing to second last element, but if i include 'self.tail = newNode' in last then it is referencing to both head and the last element.

Comment: @trincot what if I want to traverse my CircularSLL how will I stop the while loop without tail condition if I don't maintain both head and tail? Pls don't get annoyed if this question is stupid, I am a beginner
I had allowed insertion when the list is empty when I was practicing Singly LL , I knew that logic , I was lazy thats why I just returned "Head reference is None"

Comment: Not annoyed at all ;-) You only need the reference to the tail for the stop condition, not the head. The head is needed to *start* the iteration at, but that can be replaced with `tail.next` (after verification that the list is not empty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is this last line optional?

It should not be there as it introduces a bug: it makes `self.tail` equal to `self.head` which should only happen when the list has fewer than 2 nodes. But since this code is in the `else` block, it means the new node is added to a list which already has an element, and then head and tail should *not* be the same reference.

Not your question, but you should obviously deal with the other cases as well, not only where `location` is 0. And in *those* cases there is a case where you may want to add that assignment. This is the case where `location` is equal to the number of nodes that the list has (before the insertion), indicating that the insertion should happen right after the current tail, and then become the tail.

#### Suggestion

For a *circular* list it should not be necessary to maintain *two* references (head and tail). As in a non-empty list it is always supposed to be true that the head is the successor of the tail, you can choose to only maintain a reference to the tail.

Here is an implementation of how that could work:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, nxt=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = nxt or self  # Default is a self reference!
        

class CircularSinglyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tail = None

    def get_at(self, location):
        if self.tail:
            curr = self.tail.next
            for _ in range(location):
                curr = curr.next
            return curr     
    
    def insert(self, value, location=0):
        if not self.tail:
            self.tail = Node(value)
        else:
            prev = self.get_at(location - 1) if location else self.tail
            # insert node after prev
            prev.next = Node(value, prev.next)
            # if the node was inserted after the tail (and location was not 0)
            #    then make the new node the tail 
            if prev == self.tail and location:
                self.tail = prev.next

    # Iterator can serve many purposes, like printing
    def __iter__(self):  
        if self.tail:
            curr = self.tail.next
            while curr is not self.tail:
                yield curr.value
                curr = curr.next
            yield curr.value
```

Demo run:

```
lst = CircularSinglyLinkedList()
lst.insert(1)
lst.insert(2)
lst.insert(3)
lst.insert(4)
lst.insert(5, 4)
print(*lst)  # 4 3 2 1 5
```